# Resharper: Converting string on code cleanup

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a lot of strings in my project like below:

```
string myName = "John";
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + myName + "!");
```

Now, I have resharper as a Plugin installed, what I want to know is if I can set it to convert it to string.Format or even better.. string interpolation, is there a setting for this?

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {myName}");
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello {0}", myName));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you can set it up in Code Clean Up. I personally did not find such option for C#

But you can automatically reformat individual strings. Just place your cursor at the beginning of the string and press magic Alt+Enter. You will see choices to convert string to interpolation, string.Format or verbatim string

If your cursor is at the beginning of string.Format Alt-Enter will show you and option **Use string interpolation** which expands to:

- File
- Project
- Solution

Pick project and Resharper will replace all occurrences in the project accordingly

Also if you have code inspection **Language Usage Opportunities/Use string interpolation** enabled, running solution inspection will help you to detect all usages of string.format.

Happy hunting.

Comment: Really wish Code Cleanup supported this... Sadness.